# Codemagic UI (Workflow Editor) to YAML

Tags: cicd, codemagic

Am new to codemagic, I made a workflow to deploy my app to iOS and Android using the workflow editor from codemagic (aka the UI), it works like a charm but now I want to have it as a YAML in my repository (for futher replications and updates).

I read that this can be downloaded but I can't find the option (or maybe am just blind), does someone knows how to have it?.

I saw this picture on codemagic [cheat sheet](https://blog.codemagic.io/codemagic-yaml-cheatsheet/), but I dont have those options on my editor, am I missing something?.

[image: codemagic yaml cheat sheet]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately that cheatsheet blog post is a bit out of date and the functionality to create YAML from an existing Workflow Editor project is no longer available.

Codemagic does have several [Flutter sample projects](https://github.com/codemagic-ci-cd/codemagic-sample-projects/tree/main/flutter) with sample codemagic.yaml files that you could use as a starting point and there is also the `Builder mode` which you can access using the `Enter builder mode` button in the top right hand corner once you "switch to Yaml" [image: screenshot of Codemagic web UI]

Comment: Ohh thats really sad :(, I was really hoping to try this feature. But well I think we need to wait until the codemagic team makes this feature available again, thanks for the response!!